# View status of user John in termainal

Tags: ssh

I started `john` (as root) on a 16-lts server VM via ssh (putty) from a Windows VM. The Windows VM froze and needed a reboot (which broke the SSH connection). When I log back into the 16-lts Ubuntu VM and run `top` I can see `john` running as it was a few days ago. I'm wondering how I can get back to the terminal screen where you can see the progress and status of the currently running job? Thanks.

Comment: Check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22781/how-to-recover-a-shell-after-a-disconnection

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no such methods to retrieve a broken or exited terminal session. I can recommend an option, better try using **"Screen"** or **"tmux"** application for multiplexing terninal usgae while connecting remotely so that this will terminal session will continue till its exited with command. A few info can be viewed [over here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/screen.htm) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-screen-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server)  as well.